# (Programming language) How to judge whether this grammar is ambiguous

Tags: programming-languages, grammar, ambiguous-grammar

S -> ()
   | (S)
   | SS

Is this grammar ambiguous? 
and How do i judge whether this grammar is ambiguous?
I learned to draw a Parse tree. But I do not know how to draw it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following: write the grammar in the format for yacc (or any other parser generator you're familiar with). Like so

```
%%
s: '(' ')' | '(' s ')' | s s;
```

Run this through yacc, and look for error shift/reduce or reduce/reduce conflics.